# Does it seem like I'm using more memory than necessary?

Tags: modeling, performance

I'm super new to Blender, and I've been trying to model this Bose speaker to get started:

[image: Bose Speaker]

So far, I've made the base, extruded it, and then used proportional editing with scaling to make it wider in the middle.  However this is taking extremely long... when I just *move my mouse*, my entire computer (including mouse cursor) freezes for 5-10 seconds while I'm in scaling mode.  And as you can see in this screenshot, my memory usage is at 217M, which seems awfully high:

[image: Screenshot of Blender]

So my question is: Does it look like I'm going about this in some horribly inefficient way?  I'm doing this on my Macbook Pro, so I know I won't be getting as much performance as I would with better hardware, but it doesn't seem like it should be this prohibitively slow.

Comment: 61 segments of bevel looks like an overkill. Try something in the low single digits.

Comment: I imported a suzane and subsurfed it to over 7,000 faces and its only using 20 mb of RAM. Also looks like you need to recalculate the normals on your mesh because its inside out.